# How do I block Cloudflare from gaining personal data until a user agrees the cookie consent?

Tags: html, web, cookies, cloudflare

I have a website connected with Cloudflare, whenever someone accesses the website, Cloudflare automatically is gaining personal data from the website visitor (I can see the analytics in my Cloudflare dashboard). In Cloudflare Apps there are many "Cookie Consent Banner" applications which show a banner to agree or decline cookies. But how do I block Cloudflare from gaining personal data from the website visitor until they agree to such a cookie banner? I only want Cloudflare to gain information from the website visitor if they agree.
I live in the EU so I am legally obligated to make this change to my website. / I want to ensure GDPR compliance.
I was researching the internet but couldn't find useful information.